# Calling c# dll from MS Excel vba code - Compile error: Method or data member not found

Tags: c#, vba, excel, dll

This is my c# library I from which dll is generated, Also have enabled the COM visiblity in Property -> App,Build

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace howto_dll_for_excel
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
        [ProgId("howto_dll_for_excel.CSharpTools")]
        public class CSharpTools
        {
            [ComVisible(true)]
            public string AddBrackets(string value)
            {
                return "[" + value + "]";
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to access this dll in MS excel using vba as active X

I added the reference of the dll to this vba code,then created a button and this is the macro definition

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim tools As howto_dll_for_excel.CSharpTools
Dim value As String
Dim result As String
Set sheet = ActiveSheet
value = sheet.Cells(1, 1)
tools = CreateObject("howto_dll_for_excel.CSharpTools")
End Sub
```

My problem is,

Here the first access of the project howto_dll_for_excel automatically lists the CSharpTools class,

but in the last CreateObject Statement ,it is not listing,even if I type it manually prompts error

"Compile error: Method or data member not found" .

Comment: As far as I remember,  CreateObject expects a string as input, try  CreateObject("howto_dll_for_excel.CSharpTools")

Comment: Yup, he missed the quotes.

Comment: thanks for the reply,but that also doesnt work

Comment: @keerthee do you get the same error or a different error after adding the quotes?

Comment: Check whether the following registry key exists: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\howto_dll_for_excel.CSharpTools . If not then you'll have to register your DLL: regsvr32 c:\path.to\mydll.dll and then try again

Comment: Stanely I get the same error on adding quotes

Comment: Bob, the register key exists,but there are not paths found in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem was that, the dll was 32 bit and the excel was 64 bit version